# datetimepicker table-condensed overflow calendar-table

Tags: javascript, html, css, datetimepicker

I'm trying to implement https://www.daterangepicker.com/ into my Django template. currently the calendar inside which is  `table-condensed` table it's overflowing outside the `calendar-table` div
[image]

Here how i implemented in my template:

```
<script>
$('input[name="date_range"]').daterangepicker({
    "showWeekNumbers": true,
    "showCustomRangeLabel": false,
    "showWeekNumbers": true,
    "showDropdowns": true,
    locale: {
        format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
        cancelLabel: 'Clear'
    }
});
<script>
```

Does anyone know why is this happening? from inspecting the modal also outside of the container div. Is that what i should be worrying about?

UPDATE:
after inspecting the element i see where it's overflowing:



...



the table seem to be overflowing the outside div(calendar-table) as you can see

[image]

[image]

css element:

```
table-condensed css:

element.style {
}
@media (min-width: 564px)
.daterangepicker .drp-calendar.right .calendar-table {
    border-left: none;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
.daterangepicker .calendar-table {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
div {
    display: block;
}
```

calendar-table css:

```
element.style {
}
@media (min-width: 564px)
.daterangepicker .drp-calendar.right .calendar-table {
    border-left: none;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
.daterangepicker .calendar-table {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
div {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Hi. We can't guess, you shared your daterangepicker initialization but your problem is clearly an HTML/CSS one, there might be a conflict somewhere in your code. Share all relevant parts of your code :)

Comment: thank for the feedback, i will update with extra infos from the inspection

Comment: @AlexandreElshobokshy i had updated the relevant html,css to it. I think i narrowed down where it gone wrong. In the end these element are generated by the package so i hardly can control these